# HTML and Ruby on Rails - Display <br/> tags as line breaks, but other tags as strings

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, line-breaks

I'm working on my first Rails website, but I have a little problem: I want to display the <br/> tags as line breaks, but I also want to display the other tags as strings.

For example, the user input is:

```
<a href='#2'>Go to #2</a><br/><a href='#3'>Go to #3</a>
```

I want to display:

```
<a href='#2'>Go to #2</a>
<a href='#3'>Go to #3</a>
```

I know that I can display the <br/> tags as line breaks like this:

```
<%= simple_format @user_input %>
```

But the problem is that this command display:

```
Go to #2
Go to #3
```

And not:

```
<a href='#2'>Go to #2</a>
<a href='#3'>Go to #3</a>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<% @user_input.split("<br/>").each do |line| %>
  <%= line %><br/>
<% end %>
```

Output:

```
<a href='#2'>Go to #2</a>
<a href='#3'>Go to #3</a>
```

Or even better, use a regexp so you can split either `<br>` or `<br/>`:

```
<% @user_input.split(/<br\/>|<br>/).each do |line| %>
  <%= line %><br/>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE**

Some cases will fail with the above approach, for example:

```
<input type="text" value="<br/>">
```

To be able to handle those cases, you could use **Nokogiri**, already bundled with rails, but you'll need add a couple of additional steps in your code.

First, your controller:

```
def some_action
  input = "<a href='#2'>Go to #2</a><br/><a href='#3'>Go to #3</a><br><input type='text' value='<br/>'>"

  @user_input = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(input)
  @user_input.search('br').each { |br| br.replace("\n") }
end
```

Basically, you will create a Nokogiri HTML document and replace all `br` tags with `"\n"`.

Second, create a `css` class to use those `"\n"` as break lines:

```
.new-lines {
  white-space: pre-line
}
```

Now you will simply add this to your view:

```
<div class="new-lines">
  <%= @user_input.css('body').children %>
<div>
```

Notice the use of `class="new-lines"`, this is important to make each `"\n"` act as a `<br>`.

And the output:

```
<a href="#2">Go to #2</a>
<a href="#3">Go to #3</a>
<input type="text" value="&lt;br/&gt;">
```

Yes, there is a small *caveat* since the original `value='<br>'` turned into `value="&lt;br/&gt;"`, but i hope that not to be a big issue; but if it is, then you could do something like this:

```
<%= @input.css('body').children.to_s.gsub("&lt;", "<").gsub("&gt;", ">") %>
```

And the output:

```
<a href="#2">Go to #2</a>
<a href="#3">Go to #3</a>
<input type="text" value="<br/>">
```

You may need to enhance this code further for more edge cases, but i think this example will do the trick.

Also consider using a *helper* instead of throwing all the code in your controller/view.

Comment: You can't rely on regular expressions or using `<br/>` as a delimiter. This fails in cases where the character sequence `<br/>` is not actually an HTML tag, such as `<input type="text" value="<br/>">`.

Comment: @meagar Yes, you are right, for edge cases it would be better to parse the HTML and work from there. _Nokogiri_ could be handy since its already included in rails. I'll post an update to cover that scenario.

Answer (score 6):

Use the Rails sanitize helper method and whitelist the tags you want to allow and leave those out that you don't. All those left out would be stripped and shown as text. So in your case it would be something like

```
<%= sanitize @user_input, tags: %w(br) %>
```

For the sanitize method api info see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize.

Comment: It changes the <br> tags in line breaks, but the other HTML tags are not displayed to the screen...

Comment: Yes, the sanitize method escapes the html by not showing it at all except the whitelisted tags. There is not a Rails helper that will escape and display as raw only some html tags and render others. You'll have to do some Ruby tricks for that. Gerry's answer below works, just tried it out.